# Problem with launching JavaFX app, java cannot find symbols

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I wrote GUI app and I have problem with launch when I'm trying start my app i got errors that java cannot find symbols it's a lot of symbols so, here is my main class with fxml file represent main page from my app:

```
 public class GuiApp extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
            Pane mainPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/mainPane.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image("banana.png"));
            stage.setTitle("Marcin testApp");
            stage.show();
        }
    }
```

module-info.java

```
module marcin.scanner {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires libphonenumber;
    requires lombok;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires org.apache.logging.log4j;

    exports com.marcin.gui.scenebuilder to javafx.graphics;

    opens com.marcin.gui.scenebuilder.controller to javafx.fxml;
}
```

I am using others library in my project I added it in dependency and after I'm trying run my app I got errors:
[image: errors]

EDIT: response i Think that i have right imports nothing isn't red
[image: library-csvclass]

Comment: looks like you should look at the CsvFileScanner class, not the files you posted above. Do you have the proper imports? Have you got the right libraries on your path?

Comment: @Stultuske I eddited post, On the left side is library from External Libraries, next to is CsvFileScanner class and below the error messages

Comment: How did you add library for `CsvFileScanner`? Make sure its available at runtime. You can check by extracting output jar file and finding your local lib is there or not.

Comment: @user370305 I didn't add CsvFileScanner its one of class from my project, I added everything by dependency